# Selenium Manager has stopped working in Python recently

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

"selenium-manager.exe has stopped working"

Error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Downloaded file cannot be uncompressed (xml extension)', src\files.rs:46:9
note: run with 'RUST_BACKTRACE=1' enviroment to display a backtrace
```

Code:

```
import request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.commom.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver")
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

url = 'https://google.com'
driver = webdriver.chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Should be `driver = webdriver.Chrome(..)` - Notice the uppercase `C` in `Chrome`